# Long explanation of the meaning of being preferred company

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence

I am trying to grasp the essence and the meaning of being preferred is.

Comment: Have you looked it up?

Comment: @Elliot yes but I need a robust explanation of what it means to be preferred

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like company advertising or promotion. They are claiming they are preferred (the first choice) of clients looking for the kind of service they provide.  You can only verify with more context.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have already found, and the context of the phrase "preferred company". Was it something like "He is not my preferred company" or "We are a preferred company" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If one has a choice of a company, partner or store bought item to choose and takes the one that they like much more or, grading likes and dislikes in descending order, all the way down to the slightly better one it would still be the *preferred* choice. Its characteristics make a great deal of difference or perhaps just that little bit more that makes it the better choice. If the one chosen had no such distinguishing characteristics to go by then one would not have a preference, except perhaps for the least objectionable.

Comment: What about being the preferred company?